# C++ code for Palindrome numbers in a range that are palindrome when squared

Tags: c++, palindrome

When debuging this code i put the range numbers in but i dosent print out the answer. I tried writin 10 and 11. 11 is a palindrome number which when squared is 121 which should print out.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int n, m, x, y, digit, rev = 0;
  cout << "Write 2 natural numbers:" << endl;

  cin >> n >> m;

  for (int i = n; i <= m; i++) {

      x = i;

      do {
          digit = x % 10;
          rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
          x = x / 10;
      } while (x != 0);

      if (x == rev) {
          y = rev * rev;
          rev = 0;
          digit = 0;

          do {
              digit = y % 10;
              rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
              y = y / 10;
          } while (y != 0);

          if (y == rev) {
              cout << "This number is a squared palindrome number which is still a palindrome nuber: " << rev;
          }
      }



  }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What value will `rev` have at the beginning of the second iteration through our outermost `for` loop? What value should it have?

Comment: `if (y == rev)` -- Maybe it doesn't print because `y` is never equal to `rev`?

Comment: What about `0,1,2,3`

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing you should do is split the palindrome test into its own function.

This will simplify your main loop:

```
for (int loop = n; loop <= m; ++loop) {
    int loopSq = loop * loop;
    if (isPal(loop) && isPal(loopSq)) {
        std::cout << "FoundOne: " << loop << " and " << loopSq << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Don't declare variables until you need them:

```
int n, m, x, y, digit, rev = 0;
```

What do they all mean?
Give them meaningful names.
Declare one variable per line (we want the code to be easy to read and initialize).

---

Don't do this:

```
using namespace std;
```

---